# mysql data update attempt is unsuccessful

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website that lets users interact with each other. When user logs in on my there is a code that sets a field `login_status` to online in my database. This is working fine.

The problem comes when user logs off I set the same field to offline and add the logout time in a field `last_login`.
Below is the code for my **`logout.php`**

```
session_name("_user");session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$id = $_COOKIE['_d']; //this cookie has the user  id of the user

// set user offline     
$query = "UPDATE details SET login_status = 'offline' WHERE user_id = '$id";    
$update = mysqli_query($conn, $query); //not working

// set last login
$time = date("h:i:sa");
$date = date("d-m-Y");
$last = "on ". $date." at". $time;

$query = "UPDATE details SET last_login = '$last' WHERE user_id = '$id";    
$update = mysqli_query($conn, $query); // not working


// Unset all session values 
$_SESSION = array();

// get session parameters 
$params = session_get_cookie_params();

// Delete the actual cookie. 
setcookie(session_name(),'', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);

$past = time() - 100;

setcookie('_d', 'deleted', $past);
setcookie('_user', 'deleted', $past);
setcookie('uid', 'deleted', $past);
setcookie('_vip', 'deleted', $past);
setcookie('_status', 'deleted', $past);
setcookie('_edit', 'deleted', $past);

// Destroy session 
session_destroy();

header("Location: login?status=logout%20sucessful");
```

both the queries is not working and doesn't update my table details. what's the mistake I am making.

Comment: Just echo your `$query` and see what happens if you post the query in your phpmyadmin

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Errors? Blank values? You're not doing any error checking, so you may find the problem in the logs.

Comment: `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`. *Mornin' Sam*  @JayBlanchard

Comment: what do you mean by this @Fred-ii-

Comment: This => http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/

Comment: This query doesn't gets data from user input

Comment: Where does the cookie data come from? You should *always* use parameterized queries @Pushkar

Comment: cookie data is from my database. k I will keep that in mind

Comment: @Pushkar, COOKIE is stored in client computer. People can send a fake COOKIE. It is beyond your control ^^

Comment: didn't knew that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not manually concatenate your SQL query with untrusted input. This is bad practice.

Let put this aside. I spot that your query is not valid.

```
UPDATE details SET login_status = 'offline' WHERE user_id = '$id
                                                            ^
                                                        there is opening single
                                                        quote without closing
                                                        quote.
```

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo error

```
$query = "UPDATE details SET login_status = 'offline' WHERE user_id = '$id";
```

in  the above one , you missed the ' after $id. Change it as

```
 $query = "UPDATE details SET login_status = 'offline' WHERE user_id = '$id'";
```

in both queries

Answer (score 1):

Your `query` seems to have syntax error so modify your query as

```
$query = "UPDATE details SET login_status = 'offline' WHERE user_id = '$id'";  // modify single quote from $id
```

instead of

```
$query = "UPDATE details SET login_status = 'offline' WHERE user_id = '$id";
```

Same correction in your second update query.

Comment: *"`WHERE user_id = $id";`"* - If their user_id column and cookie are `int`, sure. Otherwise, it will error out.

Comment: you are right, I have made the required corrections.

Comment: You could have just made an edit under it stating it. Your original answer may have been correct, which is why it's always good to address both possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DATETIME` datatype into database for storage lastlogin. There is no sense to save "on" and "at", just add it when print message

Comment: This doesn't address the problem; stick with the question's real problem.